# (python)Determine when to end and restart(loop) twitter scraping

Tags: python, loops, twitter, web-scraping, web-crawler

Determine when to end and restart(loop) twitter scraping

Hello This is twitter scraping code. You are importing tweets that contain keywords.

What I want to do is end the crawl after 10 hours. And it is cumulative restart to the current output.

I left a note to hear the code advice on how to do this.

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson

search_term = 'word1'
search_term2= 'word2'
search_term3='word3'

lat = "xxxx"
lon = "xxxx"
radius = "xxxx"
location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)

API_key = "xxxx"
API_secret = "xxxx"
Access_token = "xxxx"
Access_token_secret = "xxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                 q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term, search_term2, search_term3),
                rpp=1000,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=True)

data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/workk2.txt", mode='w')   
data = {}   
i = 0       

for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text   
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')  
    i += 1

wfile.close()
```